# Cypress URL matching queries

Tags: routes, cypress

In Cypress.io I am trying to use cy.route to match a request to ensure the entire page has loaded before proceeding.

```
   cy.server();
   cy.route({
       'https://dev.flurosat.com/histogram**',
       method: 'GET'
   }).as(getHistogram)
```

```
  cy.wait('@getHistogram')
```

In the network tab, I am clearing getting a response but my `cy.wait` times out after the response shows up.
[image]

It appears my globbing pattern is not matching.

I have very similar `cy.route` commands within this very test, and all are received correctly, however those other commands are matching routes with globbing patterns `https://dev.flurosat.com/weather/**`, `http://dev.flurosat.com/groups/**`, where the `**` follows a `/` instead of a query string.

Is it possible to match this route?

I do not want to match with `https://dev.flurosat.com/**` as this is too generic.

Thanks

Comment: Are you calling wait just after the route ?

Comment: I set up this `cy.route`, then click the button that triggers the call, then use a `cy.wait` with an alias.  As mentioned, this pattern is working with other requests being made.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you switched the method and the URL. This syntax did work for me:

```js
cy.server();
cy.route('GET', 'https://dev.flurosat.com/histogram**').as(getHistogram)
```

You don't even have to fully write out the URL, this should work as well: `'**/histogram**'`

Comment: If I specify `method: verb`, I can order the request in this way, as it works with other requests I am testing.
I also tried your globbing pattern, and did not seem to make a difference.

Comment: hmm, that is weird. Apparently something is off with the pattern indeed, but I don't see what would be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are doing right but this works for me as well using the relative url

```
  cy.server();         
  cy.route({ method: 'GET', url: '/histogram**' }).as('getHistogram');
```